Allowing `use_filter` in Specific Areas
I am trying to edit the avatar that is called from Woocommerce's review tab in a product page. This is my piece of code that works but it also manipulates the admin menubar, which is something I do not want it to do.
I am using this hook to apply the initials of the reviewer, instead of their Gravatar image.
// Apply filter
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 1 , 5 );

function my_custom_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
    $user = false;
    
    if ( !is_product() ) return $avatar;

    if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {

        $id = (int) $id_or_email;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );

    } elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {

        if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
            $id = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
        }

    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );   
    }

    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) ) {
        $user_name = explode(" ", $user->display_name);
        $avatar = '<div class="cnc_customer-review-profile">
                <span>' . substr($user_name[0], 0, 1) . substr($user_name[1], 0, 1) . '</span>
            </div>';
    }

    return $avatar;
}

Is there a way to apply a filter to a specific part of a page?

I have added the check to confirm if we are on a product page and within the WooCommerce review section and update the code accordingly.
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar', 10, 5 );

function my_custom_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
    // Here we are checking if we are on a product page and within the WooCommerce review section.
    if ( ! is_product() || ! did_action( 'woocommerce_review_before_comment_text' ) ) {
        return $avatar;
    }

    $user = false;

    if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {
        $id   = (int) $id_or_email;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
    } elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
            $id   = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
        }
    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );   
    }

    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) ) {
        $user_name = explode(' ', $user->display_name);
        $initials  = isset( $user_name[1] ) ? substr( $user_name[0], 0, 1 ) . substr( $user_name[1], 0, 1 ) : substr( $user_name[0], 0, 1 );
        $avatar    = '<div class="cnc_customer-review-profile">
                <span>' . $initials . '</span>
            </div>';
    }

    return $avatar;
}

This should works for you.

This did not work for me, and that is due to the hook order that may cause problems. For my scenario, what worked was this logic: ! is_product() || did_action( 'admin_bar_menu' ) >= 1.
